# How could I replace the text in my document in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to replace "switch" to "on" but it's "off" and trying to replace the document with id "1" right now in my database, here is a screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zWdm.jpg. I don't know how to do that because I'm new to the mongoose.

Here is my Schema.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const switchSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
    switch: String
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model('switch', switchSchema)
```

And my index.js

```
async function switchon(){
  const replace = await cmdlogging.findOneAndUpdate(
    { switch: 'on' },
    { new: true }
  );
  await replace.findById(1);
}
```

The error is:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'findById' of null
```

Comment: I'm more familiar with the standard MongoDB node driver but I think that the first parameter of the findOneAndUpdate method should be the filter to find the element you want to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) requires a `filter` to match your document as the first argument - so in your case - as you're trying to update the document with `id` 1 - you should change it to:

```
async function switchon(){
  const updatedDocument = await cmdlogging.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: 1 },
    { switch: 'on' },
    { new: true }
  );
  // there's no need to call `findById` again, 
  // as replace holds already the updated document, since you've set { new:true } 
 return updatedDocument;
}
```